# Error apply plugin: 'com.google.gsm.google-services' also added classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I am using firebase real-time database. when i want to sync gradle i get this error message: 
Plugin with id 'com.google.gsm.google-services' not found.

I have already download google-services.json and add it to my app folder in project view
and I already tried many classpathes include:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.1'
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
```

project gradle:

```
{buildscript 
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()    
}
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and my module app is:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.esppad.friendlychat2"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}


dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.0.0'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gsm.google-services'
```

Comment: There is typo while applying plugin replace with this line apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

apply plugin: 'com.google.gsm.google-services' must not be placed inside dependencies

Add it after dependencies like below,

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.0.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gsm.google-services'
```

Comment: sorry it was like u said but i was paste it incorrectly. already edited that

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in this line: `apply plugin: 'com.google.gsm.google-services'` it should be gms not gsm, like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.esppad.friendlychat2"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}


dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.0.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: sorry it was like u said but i was paste it incorrectly. already edited that